# How to remotely access Kubernetes Dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

I am new to K8s. I have installed a Cluster on 2 Ubuntu VMs in a Cloud.
Cluster is up and running. I have also installed the K8s Dashboard, and these are the services:

```
user@vm01:~$ kubectl get all -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/dashboard-metrics-scraper-799d786dbf-xjmbg   1/1     Running   0          121m
pod/kubernetes-dashboard-546cbc58cd-t68nn        1/1     Running   0          15m

NAME                                TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
service/dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.107.246.51    <none>        8000/TCP        121m
service/kubernetes-dashboard        **NodePort**    10.105.127.123   <none>        443:32000/TCP   121m

NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper   1/1     1            1           121m
deployment.apps/kubernetes-dashboard        1/1     1            1           121m

NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/dashboard-metrics-scraper-799d786dbf   1         1         1       121m
replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-546cbc58cd        1         1         1       15m
replicaset.apps/kubernetes-dashboard-fb8648fd9         0         0         0       121m
```

so the Dashboard service is NodePort.
Then I start a proxy:

```
user@vm01:~$ kubectl proxy --address='0.0.0.0' --disable-filter=true
W0408 14:32:35.934866  206628 proxy.go:175] Request filter disabled, your proxy is vulnerable to XSRF attacks, please be cautious
Starting to serve on [::]:8001
```

Finally from my local Windows machine I open browser and type the URL:

```
http://*publicIP*:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/
```

using the public IP of the VM.

Here what I get:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"kubernetes-dashboard\" not found",
  "reason": "NotFound",
  "details": {
    "name": "kubernetes-dashboard",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 404
}
```

To me it looks that the proxy and the cluster are working but there is something wrong with Dashboard.
So the questions are:

1. is it possible to access K8s UI from remote as I am trying to do?
2. how?

Any help appreciated.
thanks

Comment: do change `*publicIP*:8001`  to `localhost:8001` as you are running proxy from your local host

Comment: no, well the proxy (if I understand where proxy should be running...) is running on the VM where there is k8s master node. So localhost from my Windows machine would never work! that's my problem indeed. Do I have to run proxy on my local Windows machine?